# Configure and Deploy Lambda Pipeline in code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-data-pipeline

I was wondering if there are any AWS Services or projects which allow us to configure a data pipeline using AWS Lambdas in code. I am looking for something like below. Assume there is a library called `pipeline`

```
from pipeline import connect, s3, lambda, deploy
p = connect(s3('input-bucket/prefix'),
            lambda(myPythonFunc, dependencies=[list_of_dependencies])
            s3('output-bucket/prefix'))
deploy(p)
```

There can be many variations of this idea of course. This use case assumes only one s3 bucket for e.g. There could be a list of input s3 buckets.

Can this be done by AWS Data Pipeline? The documentation I have(quickly) read says that Lambda is used to trigger a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing that is available is the State Machine functionality within the newly released [Lambda Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-step-functions-build-distributed-applications-using-visual-workflows/).  With these you can coordinate multiple steps that transform your data.  I don't believe that they support standard event sources, so you would have to create a standard lambda function (potentially using the [Serverless Application Model](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-simplified-serverless-application-deplyoment-and-management/)) to read from S3 and trigger your State Machine.

Comment: I think the `Serverless Application Model` fits what I need. I have to now investigate how to do that in Python :). Thanks!